# Conditionally display a Fieldset with Crispy Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to do something simple while using Crispy Forms; I want show a Fieldset only if the user belongs to the staff group. This is easily solved in a standard templates like this:

`{% if user.is_staff %}
    show extra stuff
{% endif %}`

Maybe I missed something in the manual, but I don't see how I can just inject a template tag like "{% if user.is_staff %}" into the crispy form Layout. It would be ideal for my use case if I could something like the following where I use a fictitious 'Djangotag' to solve my problem:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
   Fieldset(
       'Section One',
       'name',
       'description',
   ),
   Djangotag('{% if user.is_staff %}'),
   Fieldset(
       'Conditional Fieldset',
       'field1',
       'field2',
   ),
   Djangotag('{% endif %}'),      
   Fieldset(
       'More Details',
       'detail1',
       'detail2',
   ),
  )
```

Is there an easy way to do this with crispy forms?

---

Note: I already implemented the `self.user = kwargs.pop('user')` approach and it's not very elegant, I am still looking for something better.

I also tried created simple templates for the if statements, and tried this, `HTML("{% include 'helpers/is_staff.html' %}"),` but the render process fails.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the request context to your form from the view, and then use this in your form helper. Something like this:

In the view function that creates the form:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST, user=getattr(request, 'user', None))
```

Then in your form's `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

And finally in your form layout code:

```
if user and user.is_staff:
    self.helper.layout.append(Fieldset(
        'Conditional Fieldset',
        'field1',
        'field2',
    ),
```

I've just appended this fieldset to the end of the layout. The [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#updating-layouts-on-the-go) gives you other options for updating layouts on the fly.

Comment: That is the exact approach I started to implement. Then realized I would have to monkey around with appending the fields and the widgets, etc.  The Django framework solves this use case so elegantly, that this hack gets ugly fast and seems unacceptable to me, even though it works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a cleaner way, so I completed it the way I had started.

Here's the view...

```
class ModelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
....
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    # I am going to stuff the user object into the view so that 
    # I can use it in ModelForm to check the user and build the form
    # conditionally
    kwargs = super(ModelCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

In the ModelForm it was easiest to assume that the fields were always needed -- so I declared them all in the meta section -- then conditionally delete the fields, and conditionally append the form...

```
class YourCrispyForm(forms.ModelForm):
....
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(YourCrispyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # remove conditional fields
    if self.user and self.user.is_staff:
        pass
    else: 
        del self.fields['field_name'] 
        del self.fields['field_name'] 
        del self.fields['field_name']

    if self.user and self.user.is_staff:
        self.helper.layout.append(  
        Fieldset(
            'Conditional Sections',
            Row(
                Div('field_name', css_class="col-md-2"), 
                Div('field_name', css_class="col-md-2"),
                ...
            ),
          )
        )
```

It took me awhile to realizing that the deletion was the way to go. Hope that helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

### Do it in Python(TM)

The central idea of crispy forms is doing more things in Python and less in templates.
Therefore, my crispy forms are routinely called like this

```
  {% crispy form form.get_formhelper %}
```

In the `get_formhelper` function, I build up the `Layout` object additively from scratch, all programmatically, wherever dynamic adaptation is needed, like so:

```
import crispy_forms.helper as cfh
import crispy_forms.layout as cfl

def get_formhelper():
    helper = cfh.FormHelper()   
    layout = cfl.Layout()
    fieldset = cfl.Fieldset("Fieldset Title")
    fieldset.fields.append('myfield')
    ...
    layout.fields.append(fieldset)
    ...
    helper.layout = layout
    return helper
```

This provides maximum flexibility and keeps the layout logic nicely separate from other form logic.